# React authentication with Amazon Load Balancer and Cognito issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, amazon-cognito

I am using Amazon Load Balancer with Cognito to authenticate users on my React application. In order to achieve this, I have created two routes, to have one recognized by ALB as public and one as private so, for which, it has to prompt the authentication window if Cognito cookies are not valid.

So, in React, I defined the routes in this way:

```
<Switch>
    <Route userInfo={userInfo} exact path="/ui" >  
        <MainPage />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/">
        <StaticPage />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

So, correctly, when I click Login button on my public StaticPage, I am redirected to the Protected page and I can authenticate. Everything works as expected.

The problem happens when I logout and I try to login again. In this case, when react redirects me to /ui, it takes the copy from Disk cache and ALB is not able to recognize it as a new call and does not prompt the UI. If I refresh the page, it correctly prompts me the login page.

So, my question is, how can I force React to make a new call instead of using a cached copy (Oon chrome console I can see this: Request Method: GET Status Code: 200  (from disk cache))? I have tried to set HTML meta cache headers but it does not solve my issue.

This is my logout method:

```
function logoutAction(ctx){

    console.log("[ang94402] SessionLogout started")

    cookies.remove('username');
    cookies.remove('password');

    // Remove Cognito cookies
    cookies.remove('AWSALBCORS');
    cookies.remove('AWSALB');
    cookies.remove('C2BAuthSessionCookie-0');

    sessionStorage.clear();

    setLoginErrorMessage(null);
    setUserInfo( {username:'',organization:'',userFullName:'',apiAuth:{}});

    // Calling Cognito url to logout
    asyncCognitoCall().then(history.push("/"));

  }
```

To call /ui I tried to use Link, href, windows.locate but, without success. It is always taking the cached copy and not making a new get call.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the cookies are cleared?
I had to clear the secure cookies in serverside with get call.